# My session variables in PHP aren't saving from page to page

Tags: session, php

So it used to work and then I changed something in my code and now I can no longer access the Session variable username that I stored in my login.php file. I print it out at the end of login.php so I know it saves it, but I can't print it from the other php file. Any thoughts as to what the problem is?

test.php

```
<html>
<?php
session_start();

$temp = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "$temp";

?>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$usernm = $_POST["usernm"];

$_SESSION['username'] = $usernm;
// there is an html form that defines username

echo $_SESSION['username'];
header ('Location: http://www.ugrad.cs.jhu.edu/~rwilso70/test.php');
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<?php
session_start();

$temp = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "$temp";

?>
</html>
```

should be:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<?php

$temp = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "$temp";

?>
</html>
```

It must be done BEFORE any content is sent out as the cookie setting is an HTTP header. You should turn on [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) as this would have errored otherwise and told you what was wrong. Always develop with error reporting at its highest.

Comment: I moved all the php to the top of the file, but it still can't get the username from login.php

Comment: Turn on error_reporting first as linked in the above answer, and then report back any errors that occur. Also make sure you have cookies enabled in your browser.

Comment: @bluejay615 Then please update your question with the current code.  Even a small issue like the one identified in cryptic's answer will cause things not to work.

Comment: I turned on the error_reporting and it didn't report any errors, but it somehow works now. So I took out the error_reporting line and it still works so I guess I don't have a problem now though I'm doubtful it's completely fixed. Thank you to everyone who responded though!

Comment: The page was either cached and did not update but served stale page, or the file was not successfully uploaded when modified.

Comment: ok, it's stopped working again so it probably wasn't fixed before. I turned on error_reporting but I don't know where it's printing the errors too. Is there any way I can tell it to print on the html page in the browser?

Comment: Make sure your cookie/session expiration time is not set too low. Only explanation I have as to why it can suddenly not show the session info.

Comment: the only change I made to my code was moving all the php to before the <html> tag and also adding in the error_reporting() line right before session_start() in test.php

Comment: Change error reporting in your php.ini file or .htaccess to make it side-wide so all files will show errors. Also make sure display_errors is on if it is not.

Comment: it displays a notice that says username is an undefined index in my test.php file. I'm not sure what that means, but I've been defining it the same way this entire time so I don't know why it's only an issue now

Comment: it switches between being able to find username and not being able to find it like every 5 minutes. Now it can find username and it isn't displaying the notice I posted above but I literally haven't touched that part of the code since I last ran it

Comment: and I checked my cookies, and they're all set correctly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21168/discussion-between-cryptic-and-bluejay615)

Comment: @bluejay615 join me in chatroom

Comment: @bluejay615 has this issue been resolved?